# Rails Rename tempfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, temporary-files, roo-gem

I am using [roo-rb](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) for accessing the uploaded files. My code is like this:

```
s = Roo::Excelx.new(params[:upload][:file].tempfile.path)
```

But I am having problem with it because the generated tempfile has no extension and I'm having this exception:

> .../AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20150216-10192-13yn50s is not an Excel-xlsx file

Is there a way to rename the `tempfile.path` so that it will have a proper extension (xlsx)? Or is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully renamed a temporary file (even when deployed on Heroku) using the `fileutils`. Here is the code:

```
require 'roo'
require 'fileutils'

tmp = params[:upload][:file].tempfile
file = File.join("public", params[:upload][:file].original_filename)
FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file

s = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
```

Comment: This is not a rename, it is a copy. The resulting copied file is not a temp file, it will not be cleaned up.

Comment: `file` is not a temp file here right. It will not be clean up by garbage collector

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Yes, you can [specify the extension](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo#usage).

```
s = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(
  params[:upload][:file].tempfile.path,
  extension: :xlsx
)
```